# How to iterate through the zeroth index for every item in list in Python

Tags: python

`hand = ["3A", "3C", "3S", '4C', '5C']`
I am looking to iterate through the zeroth index using a for loop, i.e. iterating through 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, instead of 3A, 3C, etc.

All help is appreciated.

As of right now, I have for x[0] in hand, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need `3, 3, 3, 4, 5` instead of `3, 3, 3, 4, 4` ? (check last number in both) . If yes, you can use list comprehension: `[int(h[0]) for h in hand]`

Comment: `hand_faces = [ card[0] for card in hand ]` you can't index directly on the iterator variable

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri thank you for this, as it solves part of what I'm looking for, but how would I be able to iterate through and do something with the int(h[0]) of each item?

Comment: @TedBrownlow then what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```py
for x in hand:
    s = x[0]
    # do whatever with s
```